# Collision detection of detected shapes in the video?

Tags: c#, image-processing, object-detection, collision-detection, emgucv

i wrote this code , there a few seconds video (ball and court of volleyball) ,
i using Emgu CV (image processing) , i could find ball by (HoughCircles) and i drew a cirle around the ball , then i used emgu for different parts of court of volleyball (inside and outside of court and white line of court) ,
now all thing are working properly

here is my question:
What code should I write so that the program can detect which part of the court the circle I drew around the ball hit (if it hits the inside of the court and on the white line, it will display the message "IN", and if it hits the outside of the field, it will display the message "OUT")
thanks for your helps in advance

video for test (only 200 Kb) : https://filebin.net/s5nxw45g61z8wkz1/1.mp4

[image]

this is my code :

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace MainForm
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
private VideoCapture videoCapture;
private bool isProcessing;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Video Files|*.avi;*.mp4;*.wmv|All Files|*.*";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string videoPath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        videoCapture = new VideoCapture(videoPath);
        isProcessing = true;

        ProcessVideo();
    }
}
private void ProcessVideo()
{
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    Mat hsvFrame = new Mat();
    Mat ballMask = new Mat();
    Mat fieldMask = new Mat();

    // ball detection
    int frameRate = (int)videoCapture.Get(CapProp.Fps);
    int frameCount = frameRate * 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
    {

        bool success = videoCapture.Read(frame);


        if (!success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error in Frame reading!");
            break;
        }


        CvInvoke.CvtColor(frame, hsvFrame, ColorConversion.Bgr2Hsv);

        // we assume that the ball is yellow
        ScalarArray lowerYellow = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(20, 100, 100));
        ScalarArray upperYellow = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(30, 255, 255));

        // create a mask for ball detection
        CvInvoke.InRange(hsvFrame, lowerYellow, upperYellow, ballMask);

        // we assume that the court is green and blue
        ScalarArray lowerGreen = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(45, 50, 50));
        ScalarArray upperGreen = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(75, 255, 255));
        ScalarArray lowerBlue = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(90, 50, 50));
        ScalarArray upperBlue = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(120, 255, 255));

        // create a mask for court detection
        CvInvoke.InRange(hsvFrame, lowerGreen, upperGreen, fieldMask);
        CvInvoke.InRange(hsvFrame, lowerBlue, upperBlue, fieldMask);

        // apply the mask on main frame
        Mat ballResult = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.BitwiseAnd(frame, frame, ballResult, ballMask);

        // show the main frame and the result of ball detection 
        CvInvoke.Imshow("Frame", frame);
        CvInvoke.Imshow("Ball Result", ballResult);

        // detection of ball touch the court
        bool isInsideGreenArea = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(fieldMask) > 0;
        bool isOnWhiteLine = CheckWhiteLine(frame);

        if (isInsideGreenArea || isOnWhiteLine)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("IN"); // ball is inside the court
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OUT"); // ball is outside the court
        }

        CvInvoke.WaitKey(1); // wait to show the next frame
    }

    // release 
    videoCapture.Dispose();
    CvInvoke.DestroyAllWindows();
}

// function for white line around the court
static bool CheckWhiteLine(Mat frame)
{

    Mat hsvFrame = new Mat();
    CvInvoke.CvtColor(frame, hsvFrame, ColorConversion.Bgr2Hsv);

    ScalarArray lowerWhite = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(0, 0, 200));
    ScalarArray upperWhite = new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(180, 30, 255));

    // create a mask for white line detection
    Mat lineMask = new Mat();
    CvInvoke.InRange(hsvFrame, lowerWhite, upperWhite, lineMask);

    bool isWhiteLinePresent = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(lineMask) > 0;

    return isWhiteLinePresent;
 }

 }
}
```